# Manual Database Deployments to SSDT On An Existing Database in VSTS

Tags: database, migration, database-schema, sql-server-data-tools

We have a Live database project for which we currently update via manual deployments only. As part of our process improvement initiatives however, we're proposing to switch to SSDT to enable us improve and introduce some automation into our deployment process.

To facilitate a Proof of Concept, we've provisioned a test environment where we can implement and test the SSDT deployments to a clone or like-for-like representation of the existing Live database which is currently maintained in a Git repo on VSTS.

I do however have a few of concerns and queries relating to this.

1. What would be the recommended way to clone or re-create the Live database for our SSDT deployments to the test environment, without impacting the Live environment?
2. Will importing the Live database into our SSDT project and then publishing to the test environment have any adverse effect on the Live environment and can we expect any inconsistencies between the two databases following the import?
3. Should our Proof of Concept prove successful, will we need to migrate all our database assets to a new SSDT project, or can the SSDT project run in parallel with our existing Live database project and how?
4. Will any switch or migration to SSDT result in a downtime or outage for our project team?
5. If a migration of our existing database assets to a new SSDT project is not required, could we then integrate the SSDT functionality into the existing project.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through all your questions:

1. What do you mean by clone? Copy structure or with data also? In any case you'll need to import schema. Create new project and import the schema by right-clicking on the project. If you need data also, then the best way is to backup/restore.
2. SSDT doesn't naturally works with data. It has just DDLs. So when you sync the structure performance effect depends on the changes be made. Index re-creating can take a lot of time, however table creation will not use too much resources. Once again, if you are talking about backups, then you need to measure how much they affect you.
3. SSDT is the way how you store and develop your code. It's up to you to go with or not. My opinion is that SSDT is the best tool for SQL Server development, however it can become a challenge to set it up correctly.
4. As I said already that it's all depends on the changes. Some changes will not have downtime other ones can be very complex. SSDT will just generate the SQL script and there is no difference will it be ran manually or automatically by SSDT.
5. Not very sure what do you mean by migration. SSDT is the way how do you store and develop your code. Any SQL Server database can be put to SSDT (for some existing databases you'll need to put some effort to get into SSDT, but it's really possible)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Dmitrij Kultasev. I finally managed to get our POC successfully implemented. It was relatively straightforward, although I had to repeat a few tasks to achieve the desired goal.